# llvm-cov fails to generate report when run on cloud GitLab CI

Tags: swift, docker, code-coverage, gitlab-ci, llvm-cov

I have been running the following `llvm-cov report` command (which ships as part of the Swift toolchains) in Docker images (`swift:5.1`) on various environments.

```
BINARY_PATH="..."
PROF_DATA_PATH="..."
IGNORE_FILENAME_REGEX="..."

llvm-cov report \
   $BINARY_PATH \
   --format=text \
   -instr-profile="$PROF_DATA_PATH" \
   -ignore-filename-regex="$IGNORE_FILENAME_REGEX"
```

When the docker image is hosted on any machine aside from GitLab's cloud docker runners, I get the expected code coverage output:

```
Filename                                      Regions    Missed Regions     Cover   Functions  Missed Functions  Executed       Lines      Missed Lines     Cover
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ChannelHandlers/RedisByteDecoder.swift              5                 0   100.00%           3                 0   100.00%          10                 0   100.00%
ChannelHandlers/RedisCommandHandler.swift          15                 5    66.67%           8                 3    62.50%          45                11    75.56%
ChannelHandlers/RedisMessageEncoder.swift           3                 1    66.67%           3                 1    66.67%          13                 6    53.85%
Commands/BasicCommands.swift                       28                 4    85.71%          16                 2    87.50%          99                 7    92.93%
Commands/HashCommands.swift                        38                 4    89.47%          29                 1    96.55%         156                 1    99.36%
Commands/ListCommands.swift                        56                 8    85.71%          48                 5    89.58%         217                11    94.93%
Commands/SetCommands.swift                         46                12    73.91%          30                 4    86.67%         147                 4    97.28%
Commands/SortedSetCommands.swift                  172                19    88.95%         105                 6    94.29%         555                18    96.76%
Commands/StringCommands.swift                      23                 2    91.30%          21                 1    95.24%         100                 1    99.00%
Extensions/StandardLibrary.swift                   10                 2    80.00%           6                 1    83.33%          21                 1    95.24%
Extensions/SwiftNIO.swift                           9                 1    88.89%           7                 0   100.00%          38                 1    97.37%
RESP/RESPTranslator.swift                          69                 7    89.86%          10                 2    80.00%         172                10    94.19%
RESP/RESPValue.swift                               39                11    71.79%          14                 3    78.57%          69                17    75.36%
RESP/RESPValueConvertible.swift                    52                19    63.46%          15                 3    80.00%          99                22    77.78%
RedisClient.swift                                   2                 0   100.00%           2                 0   100.00%           7                 0   100.00%
RedisConnection.swift                              72                23    68.06%          47                10    78.72%         228                31    86.40%
RedisErrors.swift                                  12                 4    66.67%           6                 1    83.33%          23                 3    86.96%
RedisKey.swift                                     15                 9    40.00%          12                 6    50.00%          38                20    47.37%
RedisMetrics.swift                                  9                 2    77.78%           9                 2    77.78%          23                 2    91.30%
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                             675               133    80.30%         391                51    86.96%        2060               166    91.94%
```

However, when the same docker images running the same commands, are hosted with GitLab's cloud runners:

```
 Filename                      Regions    Missed Regions     Cover   Functions  Missed Functions  Executed       Lines      Missed Lines     Cover
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 TOTAL                               0                 0         -           0                 0         -           0                 0         -
```

I'm making sure that the code coverage data is provided correctly by the Swift Package Manager through `ls -l` and in *every* environment (including GitLab CI) I get:

```
Profdata:  -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 575608 Feb 8 19:51 .build/x86_64-unknown-linux/debug/codecov/default.profdata
Test binary:  -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 16309424 Feb 8 19:51 .build/x86_64-unknown-linux/debug/redi-stackPackageTests.xctest
```

This also happens with LLVM-8 and LLVM-9 (LLVM-7 ships w/ Swift 5.1)

For the life of me, I can't figure out why.

Environments I've tested (all running Docker Engine 19+):

```
+----------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+
|                |                 |                |                   |
|      HOST      |       OS        |      CPU       | Generates Report? |
|                |                 |                |                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| iMac 2011      | High Sierra     | sandybridge    |        YES        |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| MBP 2019       | Catalina        | skylake        |        YES        |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| mac mini 2018  | Catalina        | skylake        |        YES        |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GitHub Actions | 'ubuntu|latest' | skylake|avx512 |        YES        |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GitLab CI      | 'tags: docker'  | haswell        |        NO         |
+----------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+
```

Relevant bug reports:

- [Swift](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-12142)
- [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/202793)

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: No, and I haven't see any movement on both my Swift Bug report, or my GitLab Issue.

I may just end up using a local or cloud macOS runner

Comment: I actually use `gitlab-runner` on a Mac mini and have the same issue, unfortunately. When I run the report in terminal, it works as expected, but when I run via `gitlab-runner exec shell`, I get an empty output. Could you share a link to your gitlab issue and Swift Bug report?

Comment: Oh, that's new information! I never tried that configuration. This must be a really weird bug with GitLab CI then

Comment: I added links to the bug reports at the bottom of the main question

Comment: Just tried today - still not working {>_<}. It sounds like a GitLab issue.

Comment: Having the same problem using a gitlab-runner on MacOS 10.15.7.